# How can I create an effect of pictures like an album

Tags: video, video-editor, vegas-pro

I am using Vegas Pro 10 and I can't find a (good) way to make pictures flying through the screen. 
Well, it's a little bit difficult to describe but what I am thinking of is a screen, where you can see small pictures coming from the background and growing to the middle of the screen, these pictures come in sequence und after it reaches a certain size it fades away. (A little bit like a Picture Gallery). So there is also a little bit of an 3D-Effect included. 
Maybe the best comparable situation is when you click [WIN] + [Tab] and then you go through the windows.
Sorry for the bad eyplanation, I hope anybody gets what I am talking about ;)

Answer (score 1):

Vegas Pro 10 has two features that could help you out. Either using the Track Motion feature for the entire video track engaged with key frames, or the pan/crop feature for the shot itself engaged with key frames would allow for changes of size, shape, rotation, zooming, orientation (reverse, upside down) and such.

Here is a tutorial on Vegas (not sure of version but this will work in Pro 10) on
how to use the Track Motion feature:

Here is a tutorial on Vegas Pro 10 on how to use the Pan/Crop feature:

If you are using more than one clip or several still images, you should use the Track Motion with key frames as the Pan/Crop feature works only with the shot itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was possible in Vegas 10 already, but in Vegas Pro 13 there is a transition called "3D Fly In/Out" which you could use to achive that effect. It probably much simpler than having to deal with pan/crop. As any transition it also offers the option to store your settings and re-apply them to other events.

3D Fly In/Out let's you determine

- the start position of your event in three coordinates (x, y and z, where z is the distance from the screen)
- the number of rotations in three dimensions
- an additional lighting effect

You can apply the effect to the event by

- adding a normal fade transition to the event
- right-clicking in the fade transition
- selecting Transition-->Insert Other
- The PlugIn-Chooser-Transition Window opens. Select "Sony 3D Fly In/Out"